# How to make the Drawer of RadSideDrawer cover the full page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, telerik, uwp-xaml

I am using a **telerik** SizeDrawer control for UWP. and in it I want the drawer content to cover full page when it opens. So I tried to bind to **Actual-Width** of the page but that didn't work and then I tried to register it with sizeChanged event but width of drawer content still remains 0. unless I explicitly define it to some value like 300 then it remains 300 but I want it to cover full screen.

**CODE**

```
<telerik:RadSideDrawer Name="MainDrawer" SizeChanged="MainDrawer_SizeChanged"
                       Loaded="MainDrawer_Loaded">
    <telerik:RadSideDrawer.MainContent>
        <Grid />

    </telerik:RadSideDrawer.MainContent>
    <telerik:RadSideDrawer.DrawerContent>
        <Grid  Name="DrawerGrid" Background="Yellow">

        </Grid>
    </telerik:RadSideDrawer.DrawerContent>
</telerik:RadSideDrawer>
```

**C#**

```
private void MainDrawer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DrawerGrid.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
}
private void MainDrawer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DrawerGrid.Width = MainDrawer.Width;
}
```

Note that height of drawer grid is alright and stretches to full screen but width remains 0 and if width is untouched totally then it is 240 fixed.

Comment: Should be `MainDrawer.ActualWidth`.

Comment: I don't know anything about the `telerik` but xaml is somewhat designed to overcome these issues-es without the need to trigger on any events.

Comment: @JustinXL I have tried but Actual Width doesn't work either, it somehow overrides the width

Comment: @Stefan I knw I don't need to trigger events because It should work when I bind with Actual width of main drawer, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it -

First, define a `double` property that gets the width of the current `Window`.

```
public double WindowWidth => Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```

Then use it as a *one-time* binding source for the `DrawerLength` of your `RadSideDrawer`.

```
<primitives:RadSideDrawer x:Name="MainDrawer"
                          DrawerLength="{x:Bind WindowWidth}" ... />
```

Finally, update the `DrawerLength` whenever the size of the `MainDrawer` gets updated.

```
private void MainDrawer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) => 
    MainDrawer.DrawerLength = e.NewSize.Width;
```

---

Also note if you don't feel like doing bindings, you can replace the first two steps with one line of code, right after `InitializeComponent();`

```
MainDrawer.DrawerLength = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```

---

### Update

Looks like when the drawer is collapsed, the control itself resets its `Opacity` back to `1`, and then when you constantly update the `DrawerLength`, the edge of the drawer could come out and give a bad user experience.

You can try to throttle page size changes with *Reactive Extensions*, or you can simply set the `Opacity` of the drawer back to `0` when it's collapsed.

To do this, you just need to monitor the `DrawerState` property and when it's `Closed`, set the `DrawerGrid.Opacity` to `0`.

But remember you will also need to set it back to `1` before it gets expanded. Unfortunately there isn't an `Opening` state and `Opened` fires too late, so you have to locate the menu button and do it inside its `Click` event.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainDrawer.DrawerLength = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        // GetChildByName: https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity/blob/master/Continuity/Extensions/UtilExtensions.cs#L44
        var menuButton = MainDrawer.GetChildByName<Button>("PART_SideDrawerButton");
        menuButton.Click += (s1, e1) => DrawerGrid.Opacity = 1;
    };

    MainDrawer.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(RadSideDrawer.DrawerStateProperty, (s, e) =>
    {
        var state = MainDrawer.DrawerState;

        if (state == DrawerState.Closed)
        {
            DrawerGrid.Opacity = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am having a problem, I followed your method and now when I resize the window to smaller screen and then resize again to larger window, then it doesn't work fine, then the width of drawerLength is perfect but when I close the drawer with "MainDrawer.HideDrawer()" only some part of drawer hides and about 70 percent drawer remains on the screen. can you please let me know why this is happening? meanwhile it works perfect on smaller window.

Comment: Try to monitor the drawer width by registering the property checked callback (`RegisterPropertyChangedCallback`) n override it with window width whenever it's changed.

Comment: No, as I said drawer width is fine. because I have even checked with the XAML debugger and width of drawer remains 1366 ( which is width of my window ) but once the app is resized from small window -> larger window, then the closed drawer remains about 70 percent on the screen, actually normally is should slide out off the screen totally, but in this case it slides out 30 percent and 70 percent remains on the screen, and when I show the drawer again then the remaining 30 percent of the drawer again slides in.

Comment: if the app starts in full window then it works perfect, and it works perfect also in smaller window, problem only occurs when app is resized from smaller window to larger window. ( but it will still work fine in smaller window, even after many resizing )

Comment: Did you also use the xaml debugger to see which element is not stretching to full screen size?

Comment: I suspect this is because there's built in logic like this - if the drawer length is greater than the actual width of the full drawer control, the code behind will simply recalc the length by giving it 70% of the actual width or something. You need to use the debugger to find out which element's width is recalculated.

Comment: can I give you a very simple and minimized sample app? would you please debug it ?

Comment: RadSideDrawer is really buggy when it comes to window size changed, so I dumped it and replaced it with SplitView for now, the problem with splitview is I want the overlay DisplayMode but it automatically closes when window is resized, and I want to keep it open no matter what, unless it is closed by button or programatically

Comment: No Problem I will wait :)

Comment: I have a question, when the opacity of drawer is 0 would it still be interactive? I mean will it interfere with user experience behind it? i.e : main content? because when its opacity is 1 it sure is interactive so user cannot interact with main content behind it

Comment: should I control visisbility as well along with opacity?

Comment: In this case you don't have to worry about user interaction because the drawer is off screen. I recommend in this case don't use visibility because this avoid unnecessary redrawing. Think about this, by default, the visibility is not changed by the control anyway.

Comment: thnks a lot it works perfect now but I still don't understand the opacity part. because before when it was buggy, I was able to click on items and whole drawer content was interactive even in closed state ( because some part was on screen ) but now after opacity fix it is not interactive at all. I mean opacity is just supposed to make it invisible right? but it should still be on screen right?

Comment: I am not sure, it shouldn't be interactive unless part of the drawer somehow was still on screen. Yes, opacity doesn't block hit test. If you want to be sure, you can always toggle `IsHitTestVisible` along with opacity; or, if your elements in the drawer are not heavy, you can go with `Visibility`.

Comment: my drawer grid has a pivot which basically contains all XAML for the app including gridviews and lot of stuff. what do you recommend in this scenario, would be best to make sure that drawer content doesn't mess with user interaction of main content ( when closed )

Comment: Opacity + IsHitTestVisible are your friends here. :)

Comment: so when opacity is 0 then hit test visible should be false? and when it is 1 then hittestvisible should be true, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148596/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-touseef).